# Fourier transform of periodic distributions & local application of a result

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, periodic-functions

**Context:** I am currently working through Chapter $8$ of Anders Vretblad's *Fourier Analysis and Its Applications*. This particular chapter focuses on distributions, and builds up to the Fourier transform of such. I am currently looking at Chapter $8.7$, focused on periodic distributions.

---

**Relevant Definitions:**

- The Fourier transform and its inverse (for ordinary functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$) are defined in the following ways for this text, in one-dimension:
  $$
  \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
  \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
  \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
  \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
  \newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}
  \newcommand{\SS}{\mathcal{S}}
  \newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal{C}}
  \newcommand{\FF}{\mathcal{F}}
  \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
  \newcommand{\f}{\widehat{f}}
  \newcommand{\w}{\widehat}
  \begin{align*}
  \FF[f](\omega) &:= \int_\R f(x) e^{-i \omega x} \, \dd x \\
  \FF^{-1}[f](x) &:= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\R f(\omega) e^{i \omega x} \, \dd \omega
  \end{align*}$$
  We may sometimes define $\f := \FF[f]$ in general.
- A sufficiently-nice function $
  f : \R \to \C$ is identified identically with its distribution $T_f : \CC_c^\infty(\R) \to \C$ given by $T_f[\vp] := \int_\R f \vp$, i.e. we may refer to $f$ both as the function $f$ and the distribution $T_f$.
- **Schwartz Space:** The ***Schwartz space*** $\mathcal{S} := \mathcal{S}(\R)$ is defined as the set of all $\vp \in \CC^\infty(\R)$ such that, for any $n,k \in \Z_{\ge 0}$, we can find constants $C_{n,k}$ such that
  $$
  \left| \vp^{(k)}(x) \right| \le \frac{C_{n,k}}{ \big( 1 + |x| \big)^n }
  $$
  (i.e. $\SS$ consists of rapidly-decaying smooth functions).
- **Tempered Distributions:** The topological dual of the Schwartz class, $\SS'$, is known as the ***tempered distributions***. Hence $f \in \SS'$ if and only if it is linear as a function $f : \SS \to \C$, and continuous in the sense of sequential convergence. That is, $f : \SS \to \C$ is continuous if and only if $\,\forall\{\vp_n\}_{n \in \N} \subseteq \SS$ and $\vp \in \SS$ such that
  $$
  \vp_j \xrightarrow[\SS]{j\to\infty} \vp; \;\;\; \text{ i.e., } \;\;\; \forall n,k \in \Z_{\ge 0}, \;
  \lim_{j \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \R} \big( 1 + |x| \big)^n \left| \vp_j^{(k)} - \vp^{(k)} \right| = 0 
  $$
  then we have $f[\vp_n] \xrightarrow[\C]{n \to \infty} f[\vp]$.
- **Translation:** As a shorthand, the text likes to - given a function $f$ and $a \in \R$ - define $f_a$ to be the function $f_a(x) := f(x-a)$.
- **Periodic Distributions:** A tempered distribution $f$ is said to be ***$p$-periodic*** if $f[\vp_p] = f[\vp]$ for every $\vp \in \mathcal{S}$.
- **Simple Zeroes:** A complex function $f : \C \to \C$ is said to have a ***simple zero*** $\zeta \in \C$ if $f(z)/(z - \zeta)$ is complex-differentiable and nonzero in an open ball about $\zeta$.
- **Fourier Transform of a Tempered Distribution:** The Fourier transform $\f$ of $f \in \SS'$ is defined by satisfying a Plancherel-like formula: $\f$ is the distribution in $\SS'$ such that
  $$
  \f[\vp] = f[\w{\vp}] \text{ for all } \vp \in \CC_c^\infty(\R)
  $$

---

**Background & Questions:**

We focus on $2\pi$-periodic $f \in \SS'$ for this section, and so shall I. The goal seems to be to establish a unifying relationship between Fourier series, and Fourier transforms of periodic distributions.

Starting at the relationship
$$
f = f_{2\pi} \stackrel{\FF}{\implies} \f = \w{f_{2\pi}} = e^{-2 \pi i \omega} \f
$$
where the final equality follows by a theorem (Theorem $8.3c$ of the text). From here, then,
$$
(1 - e^{- 2 \pi i \omega}) \f = 0
$$
Hence, wherever $\f \not \equiv 0$, we have $\omega \in \Z$. Such $\omega$ are simple zeroes of the function $1 - e^{-2 \pi i \omega}$.

This is where the text begins to lose me.

- **Question $1$:** The text claims that, consequently, $1 - e^{-2 \pi i \omega}$ "behaves like" $C_n(\omega - n)$ for $n \in \Z$ for some constant $C_n$. Why is this the case? I'm guessing that, since $n \in \Z$ forms a simple zero, then
  $$
  \frac{1 - e^{- 2 \pi i \omega}}{\omega - n} = C_n \ne 0
  $$
  in an open region about $n$, and ... I'm not sure. As stated above, $C_n$ still depends on $\omega$. Perhaps we take a limit as $\omega \to n$ in $\C$ and make an appeal to a Laurent/Taylor series expansion in some respect?
- **Question $2$:** Ignoring this, the textbook makes reference to another result, $x f(x) \equiv 0$ (as a distribution) if and only if $f(x) = C \cdot \delta(x)$, for some constant $C$ and $\delta$ the Dirac distribution. The proof is straightforward. The textbook tries to apply this in a "local sense" at each $\omega = n \in \Z$, and conclude
  $$
  \f(\omega) = \sum_{n \in \Z} \gamma_n \delta_n(\omega) = \sum_{n \in \Z} \gamma_n \delta(\omega - n)
  $$
  for to-be-determined constants $\gamma_n$, later found to match those from the exponential Fourier series expansion of $f$. However, I am lost as to how this is justified.

Any ideas as to how to justify these would be welcome.

Comment: Yes, to work locally close to $\omega=n$, you can multiply by a smooth function that is $1$ close to this point and $0$ at distance more than $1/2$ for instance

Comment: If you know about discrete Fourier series, then the conclusion for $\hat{f}(\omega)$ is immediate from the Fourier inversion formulas for discrete and continuous Fourier transforms. You don't have to go through their approximation argument to get the final result.